# Create InputStreamReader from JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java

I want to to promt a user to input a filename and pass that input into a InputStreamReader to read it. Whats wrong in my Code?

```
    result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a file");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result));            

    String fileName = null;

    try {

        fileName = reader.readLine();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        System.out.println("Eingabe konnte nicht verarbeitet werden!");
        System.exit(1);

    }
```

Comment: What does the compilation error tell you?

Comment: That `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result)); `must be `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(result));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `BufferedReader` to read the `fileName` but you'll use it to read its contents later. The file name is already returned to you by the `showInputDialog()` itself. So, you need

```
String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a file");
```

If you want the user to pick a file from the local system, better use a `JFileChooser` dialog.

```
File fileObj;
String fileName, fileDir;

JFileChooser fileBrowser = new JFileChooser();
int result = fileBrowser.showOpenDialog(this);

if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

   fileObj = fileBrowser.getSelectedFile();
   fileName = fileBrowser.getSelectedFile().getName();
   fileDir = fileBrowser.getCurrentDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

   // file may not exist
   if (!fileObj.exists()) {
     // show error msg
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. i need the filename to send it to a server, so its not on my hard drive

Comment: OK, in that case, your current approach would work fine. Just get rid of the reader.

Comment: lol, i know what that means.. dont get nervous. i tried the code and finally - accepted it. see http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/I+know.html for more info hahahaha

Comment: Nein, ich bin nicht nervös. Lol! :)

Comment: damn i cant accept twice.. but this answer in german deserves it :D thank you very much btw

Comment: @RaviThapliyal ad `JFileChooser`: `getSelectedFile()` still can return an inexistent `File`. Also, I would prefer `fileBrowser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()` :)

Comment: @stuXnet Actually, I was also demonstrating the different methods available in `JFileChooser`. But, I agree it looks verbose. About the `null`, could you explain on that?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I didn't mean `null`. You can type "abcde" into the `JFileChooser` and click Open/Save, and it will return you a `File` object for "abcde" in the selected working directory - even if there is no file "abcde". So, you can't rely that a choosen file actually exists. It's just more convenient for the user.

Comment: @stuXnet You're correct. I guess, I'll reword my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The method [`JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) you used returns a `String` object, containing the entered text - so your `result` have to be a `String` too. I guess it will contain the path to the file you want to read.

If you look at the [constructors of InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), you will notice that you can't instantiate a new one with a `String`.
But there is no need to, since you don't want to read from the `String` representing the path, but from an `InputStream` of a `File`.

Try this:

```
String path= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a file");
File file = new File(path);


try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  
    String firstLine = reader.readLine();
} catch (IOException | FileNotFoundException ioe) {

    System.out.println("Eingabe konnte nicht verarbeitet werden!");
    System.exit(1);

}
```